# MySQL UNION query correct handling for 3 or more words

Tags: mysql, select, union

I've to ask your help to solve this problem.

My website has a search field, let's say user writes in "Korg X 50"

In my database in table "products" i have a filed "name" that holds "X50" and a field "brand" that hold "Korg". Is there a way to use the UNION option to get the correct record ?

And if the user enters "Korg X-50" ?

Thank you very much !

Matteo

Comment: Why UNION? Why not something like this: WHERE name LIKE '%X50% OR brand LIKE '%Korg%' ? Or you can use AND

Comment: @Alex K is right. I provided a "UNION" since that's what the question asked for, but you don't really need that. You need a where clause with name like ... or brand like ... or whatever like whatever...

Comment: Because i cannot know how many keywords the users types in (i think)

Comment: @matteo What will be with your RDBS when user enters three or more words? May be you should use fulltext search

Comment: @Everybody Thanks a lot for taking time to help me out. I've read all your post and go to try everyone of them. I don't even know what a "fulltext search" is. Think i have to learn mysql a lot better :)

Comment: @matteo FYI: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should use [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

```
SELECT brand, name, MATCH (brand,name) AGAINST ('Korg X 50') AS score
FROM products WHERE MATCH (brand,name) AGAINST ('Korg X 50')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Have to change my index field to "fulltext" to use this right ?

Comment: @matteo The quote from official manual: A full-text index in MySQL is an index of type FULLTEXT

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you don't need `UNION` but something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE CONCAT(field1, field2) LIKE '%your_string%'
```

On client side you get rid of all characters (like space, hyphen, etc) in `your_string` that appears in user input and cannot be in `field1` or `field2`.

So, user input `Korg X 50` as well as `Korg X-50` becomes `KorgX50`.

Comment: @a1ex07 What will be in case this string: X-50 Korg?

Comment: @Alex K : I know the solution I posted is naive. To handle the case you mentioned I would:  1. Split user input and create an array. 2. For each permutation create `or` (surely, it makes sense for a small number of pieces only), so we will have `WHERE CONCAT (...) LIKE '%perm1' OR CONCAT(...) LIKE `%perm2` OR etc.`. Another way is to do it as you said in your comment (no `CONCAT`, just `field1 LIKE ... AND field2 like ...`), but it still requires splitting input and compare each chunk.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to get some form of searchable text.

either parse out the input for multiple key words and match each separately, or perhaps try to append them all together and match to the columns appended in the same way.

you will also need either a regex, or maybe a simpler search and replace to get rid of spaces and dashes after the append before the comparison.

in general, allowing users to search for open ended text strings is more complicated than 'what union do i use'... you will ideally also be worried about slight misspellings and capitalization, and keyword order.

you may consider pulling all keywords out from your normal record into a separate keyword list associated with each product, then use that list to perform your searches.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to parse user input and use as it is, then you will need to use a query like this

```
select * from products where concat_ws(' ',brand,name) = user_input -- or
select * from products where concat_ws(' ',brand,name) like %user_input%
```

However, this query won't return result if user enters name "Korg X-50" and your table contains "Korg" and "X50", then you need to do some other thing to achive this. You may look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex however it won't be a complete solution. Look for text indexing libraries for that ex: lucene